# Use If statement with multiple criteria in MS access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have one table called "EmployeeHours" where I have following columns:

**Agent_Name    Agent_Number    Start_Date  Time    State   Duration    week    Team**

Under State column I have "After Call", "Training", "Lunch", "Tea Break" etc. Out of these "After Call and Training" are considered work hours and others are "Non work Hours". I want to add a column to this table which does this identification of work and non work hours.

I know How to do it in Excel: I have done it using the IF OR condition but I am facing difficulty in doing the same thing in MS access..

Anyone knows how to implement this IF OR Criteria in MS access and prepare that column?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Something you can do that does not fully normalize your database but still gives the functionality you are looking for is to create a mapping table where you will have the different states ("After Call", "Training"...) and another field where you will have its correspondance to Work / Non work hours.

When this is done, you can create a query to calculate the Work / Non work correspondance by putting both tables in the query and linking on the Status field.

If you want you can also take this opportunity to create a table "State" with the different states in text format and with a uniquely identifying surrogate key (think Autoincrement) and replace the values in your current table with those. That way you will not sure as much text in your database (lighter) and you will be able to change the description at a single place instead of all the occurrences if you ever need to.

Answer (score 3):

In a stored query, table calculated column, or form control you can use the [IIF()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IIf-Function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3?CorrelationId=912c7c8e-c885-45e5-9e9d-9cf555bbb10a&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) function.

```
IIF([State]="After Call" OR [State]="Training", "Work hours", "Non work hours")
```

Comment: This has the drawback of being severely tedious to update if the list of status becomes large.